# Should my Play services always be asynchronous calls with promises?

Tags: java, asynchronous, playframework, playframework-2.0

I just [read](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.2.x/JavaAsync) that it is recommended to use asynchronous method calls on the server via promises when executing long running requests.  [The documentation](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.2.x/JavaAsync) says this is because the Play server will block on the request and not be able to handle concurrent requests.

Does this mean all of my web requests should be asynchronous?

I'm just thinking that if I want to to increase my web pages rendering times that I would make a series of ajax calls to fetch needed page regions concurrently.  Since I would potentially make multiple ajax calls, my Play controller methods need to be asynchronous.

Am I understanding this correctly?  The syntax is quite verbose so I want to make certain I don't take this concept overboard.  **It would seem strange to me that I have to do this given other web severs such as Glassfish or IIS automatically handle pooling.**

Answer (score 1):

Here are some detailed docs on Play's thread pools, various different configurations, how to tune them, best practices etc:

http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.2.x/ThreadPools